# Convince Idris about recursive call totality

Tags: idris, totality

I have written the following type to encode all possible rational numbers in it:

```
data Number : Type where
    PosN : Nat -> Number
    Zero : Number
    NegN : Nat -> Number
    Ratio : Number -> Number -> Number
```

Note that `PosN Z` actually encodes number `1`, while `NegN Z` encodes `-1`. I prefer such a symmetric definition to that given by `Data.ZZ` module. Now I've got a problem with convincing Idris that addition of such numbers is total:

```
mul : Number -> Number -> Number
mul Zero _ = Zero
mul _ Zero = Zero
mul (PosN k) (PosN j) = PosN (S k * S j - 1)
mul (PosN k) (NegN j) = NegN (S k * S j - 1)
mul (NegN k) (PosN j) = NegN (S k * S j - 1)
mul (NegN k) (NegN j) = PosN (S k * S j - 1)
mul (Ratio a b) (Ratio c d) = Ratio (a `mul` b) (c `mul` d)
mul (Ratio a b) c = Ratio (a `mul` c) b
mul a (Ratio b c) = Ratio (a `mul` b) c

plus : Number -> Number -> Number
plus Zero y = y
plus x Zero = x
plus (PosN k) (PosN j) = PosN (k + j)
plus (NegN k) (NegN j) = NegN (k + j)
plus (PosN k) (NegN j) = subtractNat k j
plus (NegN k) (PosN j) = subtractNat j k
plus (Ratio a b) (Ratio c d) =
    let a' = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) a in
    let b' = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) b in
    let c' = assert_smaller (Ratio c d) c in
    let d' = assert_smaller (Ratio c d) d in
    Ratio ((mul a' d') `plus` (mul b' c')) (mul b' d')
plus (Ratio a b) c =
    let a' = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) a in
    let b' = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) b in
    Ratio (a' `plus` (mul b' c)) c
plus a (Ratio b c) =
    let b' = assert_smaller (Ratio b c) b in
    let c' = assert_smaller (Ratio b c) c in
    Ratio ((mul a c') `plus` b') (mul a c')
```

Interestingly when I press Alt-Ctrl-R in Atom editor it's all fine (even with `%default total` directive). However, when I load this into the REPL it warns me that `plus` is possibly not total:

```
   |
29 |     plus Zero y = y
   |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Data.Number.NumType.plus is possibly not total due to recursive path 
Data.Number.NumType.plus --> Data.Number.NumType.plus
```

From the message I understand that it's worried about these recursive calls to `plus` in patterns handling ratios. I thought that asserting that `a` is smaller than `Ratio a b` etc. would solve the problem, but it didn't, so probably Idris sees that, but has trouble with something else. I cannot figure out what it could be, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert_smaller (Ratio a b) a` is already known to Idris (`a` is an argument to the "bigger" `Ratio a b` type after all). What you need to prove (or assert), is that the result of `mul` is structurally smaller than the arguments to `plus`.

So it should work with

```
plus (Ratio a b) (Ratio c d) =
    let x = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) (mul a d) in
    let y = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) (mul b c) in
    Ratio (x `plus` y) (mul b d)
plus (Ratio a b) c =
    let y = assert_smaller (Ratio a b) (mul b c) in
    Ratio (a `plus` y) c
plus a (Ratio b c) =
    let x = assert_smaller (Ratio b c) (mul a c) in
    Ratio (x `plus` b) (mul a c)
```